# py2exe for distribution: Executable crashes

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, executable, py2exe

I am trying to make a single `executable` out of my application that uses `matplotlib` using `Python 2.7` and `py2exe`. So, I have this standard routine:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import zmq.libzmq
import py2exe
import glob 
import matplotlib
import shutil

ico_file = "C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/newIcon.ico" 

setup(  windows = [{
            "script":"myApp.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, ico_file)]
            }], 
        options={
            'py2exe': {
                'includes':['zmq.backend.cython', 
                            'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_blas',
                            'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack',
                            'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'],
                'excludes':['zmq.libzmq'],
                'dll_excludes':['libzmq.pyd'],
                'bundle_files': 2, 
                'compressed': True
                }
            },
        zipfile=None,
        data_files=[ ('lib', (zmq.libzmq.__file__,), ico_file) ] + matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
    )
```

**Problem Definition** The created file, `myApp.exe`, does not run after double clicking on it (or calling from `cmd`). So, I used `Dependency walker` and I can see that `zlip.pyd` is missing:

```
LoadLibraryA("c:\users\mypc\documents\myapp\bin\dist\zlib.pyd") returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
```

Now if I change `'bundle_files': 3`, I have `myApp.exe` running just fine, though I get a cluttered  distribution directory. Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: What version of py2exe?  There were changes recently for bundling of files - you may need to retrieve latest from svn.

Comment: I am using `py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7`.

Comment: An upgrade may address it - I have `0.6.10`.  I know bundle_files works better in the latest version.  I'm not using `zlib.pyd` though, so it's a suggestion, not a solution.

Comment: Did not work with `0.6.10` either. So, as an alternative, is it possible to tell `py2exe` to put the dependencies in another folder, but not directly inside the `dist` folder? It is just to avoid a cluttered distribution with too many files.